# Running multiple schedules in laravel(octobercms)

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have these schedules to be executed

```php
public function registerSchedule($schedule)
{
  $schedule->call('Corymillz\Adverts\Component\PaidBoost@onPaidBoostMsb')
           ->everyMinute();
  $schedule->call('Corymillz\Adverts\Component\PaidBoost@onPaidBoostMbb')
           ->cron('0 */12 * * *');
  $schedule->call('Corymillz\Adverts\Component\PaidBoost@onPaidBoostMeb')
           ->cron('0 */6 * * *');
  $schedule->call('Corymillz\Adverts\Component\PaidBoost@onPaidBoostBmsb')
           ->daily();
  $schedule->call('Corymillz\Adverts\Component\PaidBoost@onPaidBoostBmbb')
           ->cron('0 */12 * * *');
  $schedule->call('Corymillz\Adverts\Component\PaidBoost@onPaidBoostBmeb')
           ->cron('0 */6 * * *');
}
```

When I run

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

it seems only the first schedule is executed because it shows

> running scheduled command: Corymillz\Adverts\Component\PaidBoost@onPaidBoostMsb

I am on localhost, is this the way it runs on localhost? or are my scheduled tasks organized wrongly?

Comment: Your cron expressions are not valid

Comment: @Saly3301 its looks like valid and if its not valid i would suggest please point out what is wrong so he at least know what he is doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple schedules. It was never limited to one.

When you did run `php artisan schedule:run` the conditions are not met for the other schedules to be run.

The cron task `php artisan schedule:run` should be run every minute as recommended by Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to understand how it works.

> If we take interval of 1 minute for scheduler cron to run
> [ here we are running it manually, still it will use 1 minute as per laravel/[cron-expression] design ]

```
It checks interval base on minutes for => minute based crons
It checks interval base on day's first hour's first minute for => day based crons
and so on ...
```

> **For Ex:**
> If your cron is set to run every 2 minute. `0 */2 * * *`

And we are assuming current time is : `02:00PM`

`0 */2 * * *` will run only under this time intervals

```
02:00PM to 02:01PM
02:02PM to 02:03PM
02:04PM to 02:05PM
02:06PM to 02:08PM
and so on ...
```

current time is : `02:00PM`
-> now if you run `php artisan schedule:run`
your cron will run as current time is in between 02:00PM to 02:01PM

> NEXT execution time will be in between 02:02PM to 02:03PM

**NOW, if you run `php artisan schedule:run` at 02:01:30PM nothing will
happen as its not falling under any run time interval**

> **Now your scheduler tasks**

---

```
1. everyMinute => every minute
2. '0 */6 * * *' => every 6th minute
3. '0 */12 * * *' => evry 12th minute
4. daily => each day
```

> 1. everyMinute

it will execute all the time no matter when you fire
`php artisan schedule:run`

> 2. `0 */6 * * *` every 6th minute

It has 6 minute interval, so execution patter will be. [ suppose its 2:00PM current time ]

```
-> it can execute between this time
02:00PM to 02:01PM 
02:06PM to 02:07PM 
02:12PM to 02:13PM 
02:18PM to 02:19PM 
and so on ...
```

so, to execute your

```
$schedule->call('Corymillz\Adverts\Component\PaidBoost@onPaidBoostMeb')
           ->cron('0 */6 * * *');
```

> Time should be correct.

**first make sure you set your time zone correctly. means if you print**

```
dd(\Carbon\Carbon::now());
```

> **It should show/print time on web-page exactly as your computer/machine time**

Now run `php artisan schedule:run` -> at specific interval as I define above

**For ex:**
If your clock time is : 5:13PM

then you need to wait to get it `6 minute * 3 => 18`
so next interval is `5:18PM to 5:19PM`

> run `php artisan schedule:run` command in between `5:18PM to 5:19PM`
>
> **your can see your cron executing surely.** also for other cron time you can calculate time interval your self based on above logic and run scheduler within that interval to execute other crons.

if any doubts please comment.